# Is it possible to do any computation at all in Wolfram Player for iOS?

Tags: wolfram-player

For the sake of simplification, say 2+2=?

I see a lot of beautiful rotation of solids in the examples but I would like to compute a small notebook that I have going in Mathematica. I know that is a Player, not the full Mathematica.

Comment: Did you hit ***SHIFT-RETURN*** after you typed `2 + 2`    ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Traveling, back on Monday.

Comment: Back again. I have authored the notebook in Mathematica and it works just fine. And yes, now it is in the iPad, looks like the original (answer to #Phil). #David G. Stork: But I cannot do anything with it. I cannot touch the square parentheses on the right and pressing shift-return does nothing (it should do a computation). So I am back to my original question.

Comment: Don't hit the square parentheses.  Instead, put your cursor immediately after the "2"... just as if you were to hit ***RETURN*** in a word processor, but instead you hit ***SHIFT-RETURN***.

Comment: I did answer this before but I must have made a mistake because it is not here. I have made in Mathematica a very small NB (2+2=) took it to the cloud, and loaded it into the player. So, Thank you @David G Stock, the problem is that I do not have a cursor in there. In fact I cannot do anything at all. (I can scroll the large NB but see no cursor there either).

Comment: Someone should provide an explicit answer because there is no cursor or keyboard in an iPad. Hence, I do not see how to do a computation (after paying the 10$ to enable Player) and would like to know how to run a CDF that works fine in the PC and in the cloud.

Comment: Clarifications about the question which are not just comments, should be provided by ***editing*** ([edit]) the question.

Answer (score 5):

Notebooks (and CDF files) cannot be created in the Wolfram Player for iOS app. It is only a player. They must be authored on a computer with a licensed version of Mathematica, or on the Wolfram Cloud. Wolfram provides a free Mathematica license for all Raspberry Pi computers. I recommend trying a free Wolfram Cloud account and seeing if that's sufficient for your needs. Finally, you could request a 30-day trial of Mathematica from Wolfram.

I can't tell from your question if you already have your Wolfram notebook. If so, you should be able to side-load it into the app now.

Wolfram could have a full-blown Mathematica environment on the iPad and probably will in a year or two. I'm guessing the price for a full environment would be rather high. While it's somewhat convoluted to create Notebooks for iOS, it can be done for free.

Comment: I wonder how a `form` wrapped inside an `Evaluate` inside a `Manipulate` will look like..